# A specific question about a factor theorem proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know there are tons of answers to questions about the factor theorem, however, I couldn't find what I was looking for so apologies if someone has already answered this before.

Since

$\frac{x^k - y^k}{x-y} = x^{k-1}y^0 + x^{k-2}y^1 + x^{k-3}y^2 + ... + x^1y^{k-2} + y^{k-1}$

${x^k - y^k} = (x-y)(x^{k-1}y^0 + x^{k-2}y^1 + x^{k-3}y^2 + ... + x^1y^{k-2} + y^{k-1})$

hence ${x^k - y^k} = (x-y)q_k(x)$

As usual, we write our polynomial $ p$ as

$p(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0 $

$p(x)-p(y) = $

$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0 $

$ -(a_ny^n + a_{n-1}y^{n-1} + ... + a_1y + a_0)$

$= a_n(x^n-y^n) + a_{n-1}(x^{n-1}-y{n-1}^) + ... + a_1(x-y)$

The terms have the form $a_k(x^k-y^k)$. But $x^k-y^k = (x-y)q_k(x)$, and substitute this in:

$p(x)-p(y)=$

$a_n(x-y)q_n(x) + a_{n-1}(x-y)q_{n-1}(x) + ... + a_1(x-y)$

$(x-y)(a_nq_n(x) + a_{n-1}q_{n-1}(x) + ... a_1)$

$= (x-y)q(x)$ where $q(x) = a_nq_n(x) + a_{n-1}q_{n-1}(x) + ... a_1$

If $p(a) = 0$ and $y = a$ then

$p(x)-p(a) = (x-a)q(x) $ Q.E.D

**My question is**: why we don't write $p(x) - p(y)$ as

$a_n(x-y)q_n(x) + a_{n-1}(x-y)q_{n-1}(x) + ... + a_1(x-y)q_1(x)$

$(x-y)(a_nq_n(x) + a_{n-1}q_{n-1}(x) + ... a_1q_1(x))$.

NOTE! That I'm asking whether or not $a_1q_1(x) = a_1$
Can anyone please explain this to me thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question? You can write it like that. But what is the point of such writing?

Comment: What's the point in doing such a complicated proof of a very simple fact? Since $f(x)=p(x)-p(a)$ is a polynomial and $f(a)=0$, then $f(x)$ is divisible by $x-a$, that is, $p(x)-p(a)=(x-a)q(x)$ for a polynomial $q(x)$.

Comment: So are you saying that $a_1q_1(x) = a_1$? I just want an answer to my question.

Comment: Also, I haven't gotten to polynomial division yet, that comes after understanding this proof in my math book lol.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what's happening. 
Observe that $q_1$ is just the constant $1$ polynomial.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific :d

Comment: Are you saying that

Comment: $(x-y)(a_nq_n(x) + a_{n-1}q_{n-1}(x) + ... a_1) $ =

Comment: $(x-y)(a_nq_n(x) + a_{n-1}q_{n-1}(x) + ... a_1q_1(x))$

Answer (score 0):

$q_1$ = 1

$q_k(x) = x^{k-1}y^0 + x^{k-2}y^1 + x^{k-3}y^2 + ... + x^1y^{k-2} + y^{k-1}$

Therefore, letting $k = 1$,

$q_1(x) = x^{1-1}y^0 = x^0y^0 = 1$

So they are right. Rather than write $q_1(x)$, they can just drop it.